# PHP: Assigning a multi-dimensional array to a session

Tags: php, arrays, session

Working a project and having challenges assigning multi-dimensional array to a session.

Project Info:

Companies are expected to register/book for courses on the site and a company can register more than one course and for each course, the company must specify the number of candidates and their bio data.

Example:

If Company XYZ registers for Course A, Course B and Course C. And for each course provides candidate info as follows:

```
<?php

 $all_reg_courses = array
  (
  $course_id => array(
    "candidate_no" => $cand_no,
  "all_candidates" => array(
 array
  (
  'cand_name' => 'Alex Holmes',
  'cand_email' => 'al@yah.com',
  'cand_sex' => 'Male',
  'cand_phone' => '070043635690',
  'cand_job' => 'IT'
  ),
 array
  (
  'cand_name' => 'Tilla Reel',
  'cand_email' => 'till@yah.com',
  'cand_sex' => 'Female',
  'cand_phone' => '0700833435690',
  'cand_job' => 'HR'
  ),
 array
  (
  'cand_name' => 'Bill Enya',
  'cand_email' => 'bill@yah.com',
  'cand_sex' => 'Male',
  'cand_phone' => '07008055435690',
  'cand_job' => 'Admin'
  )
  )
  ),
  $course_id => array(
    "candidate_no" => $cand_no,
  "all_candidates" => array(
 array
  (
  'cand_name' => 'Alan Pole',
  'cand_email' => 'al@yah.com',
  'cand_sex' => 'Male',
  'cand_phone' => '07009973635690',
  'cand_job' => 'IT'
  ),
 array
  (
  'cand_name' => 'Coleen Curtis',
  'cand_email' => 'cole@yah.com',
  'cand_sex' => 'Female',
  'cand_phone' => '5553435690',
  'cand_job' => 'HR'
  )
  )
  ),
    $course_id => array(
    "candidate_no" => $cand_no,
  "all_candidates" => array(
 array
  (
  'cand_name' => 'Tamia James',
  'cand_email' => 'tam@yah.com',
  'cand_sex' => 'Female',
  'cand_phone' => '7673435690',
  'cand_job' => 'HR'
  )
  )
  )
  );

?>
```

These data provided for the various courses and the candidates nominated for each course will be stored temporarily in a session and would eventually be sent into the database if "Company XYZ" finally click the 'final submit button' else all the data in the session will be destroyed after a specific time (i.e course booking cart will be emptied)

I have been trying to assign the sample multi-dimensional array above into a session but it's not just working.

Being getting an error message : Cannot use string offset;

Here is the code for appending the array to the session:

```
<?php

session_name("cand_cart");
session_start();

$c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
//$cand_no = $_POST['cand_no'];

$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cands'] = array();
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id'] = array();
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cand_no'] = array();

$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cand_no'] = $_POST['cand_no'];
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id'] = $_POST['c_id'];

//$candidates = array();

foreach ($_POST['candidate'] as $i => $can)
{
    $candidates[$i] = array();

    foreach ($can as $key => $value)
    {
        //$candidates[$i][$key] = $value;
        $_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cands'][$i][$key] = $value;
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($candidates);
print_r($_SESSION['cand_cart']);
echo '</pre>';

echo "<br><br>";

?>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Position</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php

foreach ($_SESSION['cand_cart'] as $i => $can)
{
    $c = (object) $can;
    $sn = $i + 1;
    echo '<tr><td>' . $sn . '</td><td>' . $c->name . '</td><td>' . $c->phone . '</td><td>' . $c->email . '</td><td>' . $c->sex . '</td><td>' . $c->pos . '</td></tr>';
}

?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Would be very grateful getting help with this.. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact PHP error?

Comment: @Rygu, "Cannot use string offset;" is written there

Comment: Do you get a line number? It might be here ` $_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cands'][$i][$key] = $value;` because you never seem to be making it go down to some many dimensions. However, I would consider using proper object oriented objects rather than a cacophony of multi-dimensional arrays, it is just going to haunt you wherever you are going to use this. OOP was invented for a reason, and PHP5 was made fully object oriented for the same reason... just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these lines:

```
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cands'] = array();
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id'] = array();
```

to

```
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id'] = array();
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cands'] = array();
```

Comment: dont seem to understand your answer cos this is exactly what i have in the code...would appreciate if you can be more detailed.

Comment: Thanks i got the error off and it's working but the real problem is that, I'm unable to assign more than one course id and candidate info to the session. i.e the newly asigned set of course info and it nominated candidate info overwrites the existing data in the session. And i need to store more than one course info and candidates info. Would be grateful if you could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the whole arrays, loosing the previous stored information

```
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cands'] = array();
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id'] = array(); // here you overwrite the whole 'c_id' array and loose cands

$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id']['cand_no'] = $_POST['cand_no'];
$_SESSION['cand_cart']['c_id'] = $_POST['c_id']; // another overwite
```

Comment: thanks! but how do i assign the $_post['c_id'] to the session without overwriting it?

Answer (score -1):

It would be much easier to serialize und unserialize the data before storing it into the session. This seems to be more lightweight and you wouldn't have to set each value specifically:

```
// Build up your data-Array from the submitted values stored in $_POST
$data = array();
foreach($_POST['candidate'] AS $i => $can)
{
     // Do your logic here, like you did before with the session
}

// Now serialize and store into session at once (= more performance)
$_SESSION['data'] = serialize($data);
```

If you want to use the data within the next request you will have to unserialize it:

```
$data = unserialize($_SESSION['data']);
```

Hope this helps.